# Defining a function to reverse a string in Python

Tags: python

I wrote this function to reverse a string in Python but it doesn't work, I just get the output: "gnirts tupni"

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
def transcribe_1(input_string):
 output_string = 'input string'[::-1]
 return output_string
if __name__ == "__main__":
  print(transcribe_1('Reverse this string'))
```

Comment: Look again at your 2nd line of code.

Comment: Use `output_string = input_string[::-1]` instead of `output_string = 'input string'[::-1]
`.

Comment: You have asked Python to reverse `'input string'`. Learn to use variable names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the variable `input_string` instead of the literal `input string`:

```
output_string = input_string[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have put 'input string' in quotes in the second line. This means you are not referencing the parameter and reversing it, but reversing the literal string 'input string', which is ... 'gnirts tupni'

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the single quotes on your output_string declaration:

Output_string = input_string[::-1]

This way you are referring to the parameter that was given to the function.

By having the single quotes there you're just saying output_string is equal to the reversed version of the string 'input string'.